# How can I ensure I have no gaps in my primary key values, even after deletes?

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I'm deleting some rows from my database table. Then I want to update the IDs of other rows.

For example, this is my table:

```
id |   name
1  |   aaaa
2  |   bbbb 
3  |   cccc 
4  |   dddd
```

Now I delete row number 3. I want to get a table like this:

```
id |   name
1  |   aaaa
2  |   bbbb 
3  |   dddd
```

But I get this table:

```
id |   name
1  |   aaaa
2  |   bbbb 
4  |   dddd
```

This is my code:

```
    SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = getListView()
        .getCheckedItemPositions(); 
    int itemCount = getListView().getCount();
    int[] tab = new int[itemCount];

    for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        tab[i] = itemCount - i;

        if (checkedItemPositions.get(i)) { 
            adapter.remove(list.get(i));
            db.deleteMyPlace(new MyPlacesTable(tab[i]));

        }

    }
```

And the delete method

```
public void deleteMyPlace(MyPlacesTable myPlace) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_MY_PLACES, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(myPlace.getID()) });
        db.close();
    }
```

What can I do?

Comment: Is there a reason why the ids have to be without gaps? Usually data ids should never change. Why don't you do that just in the code? Loop through your items and number them there.

Comment: The whole purpose of the `id` column is to serve as a unique immutable identifier for each row.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Ommiting id how to delete that row?

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a key, you need to renumber all the values greater than it by decreasing them by one.  If that sounds expensive, that is because it is.  BTW You also have to re-number all the references to those IDs as well.

A less expensive alternative is to move the last entry to the deleted entry.  This reduces the number of entries which need to be changed, but the complexity of the updates and the number of tables to change is the same.

Usually the simplest solution is to not change IDs as they don't cost any thing to have blanks or create new ones.  However re-numbering them is expensive and tricky to get right.